# Transfer request to another POD using Nginx

Tags: linux, azure, docker, nginx, azure-aks

I have an e-commerce application developed using following tech:
1) Front end -- react
2) Back end -- node
Back end is a microservices based architecture. Both the front end and back end are deployed in Azure Kubernetes Services.

Web server is Nginx. We are planning to cut over from old site to new site. We are getting requests on old site and want to transfer the request to a POD for transformation of old url to new URL. The requirement is much like Server.Transfer in IIS. Is there a construct in Nginx which can help us do this?

Please advise.

Comment: can't able to understand properly. are you looking forward to having rewrite rules on kubernetes nginx? rewrite old url to new url ?

Comment: Can you share a little more about your actual setup, your current behavior, and your expected behavior?  Looking up things like Nginx `proxy_pass` and the Kubernetes Ingress system could be useful, but I think we need a little more context for a complete answer.

Comment: @David Maze We want to transform the URL from "abc.com/product.aspx?category=man" to "abc.com/product/man". The job of transformation is taken care by NODE APP deployed as POD in Azure Kubernetes Services. We are looking for nginx to handle this redirection to the corresponding pod. The Node APP needs a input parameter as entire URL request.